# Who coined the "original" User story template

Tags: agile, scrum, user-stories

I'm looking for some background on this template (need a citation for a report). Who was the person who came with the well known template?

“As a [user], I want [function], so that [value]”

I've been looking for the answer but no one gives a proper citation.

Comment: I doubt there is a proper citation. For decades now, sales people have been drilled in selling based on features and benefits (and telling potential customers how features provide specific benefits). This is little more than re-phrasing to make the same statement from a different viewpoint.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be something like that after searching for 2 hours.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kent Beck [coined](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?UserStoryAndUseCaseComparison) the term *User Story* and he wasn't using the template you're mentioning but some kind of free form to capture requirements on [a card](http://xprogramming.com/xpmag/expCardConversationConfirmation):

> So I say, "Tell me the stories of what the system will do. Write down the name of the story and a paragraph or two."

**But it's [Dan North](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DanNorth) that suggested the [User Story Template](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?UserStoryTemplate) on the [eXtreme Programming Yahoo Group](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/extremeprogramming/message/83897)**.

And Mike Cohn ([who recommended](http://blog.mountaingoatsoftware.com/advantages-of-the-as-a-user-i-want-user-story-template) using the template in his User Stories Applied book) contributed to make it popular.

Answer (score 3):

Evidence exists that suggests [Connextra used the template format as early as 2001](http://agilecoach.typepad.com/photos/connextra_user_story_2001/connextrastorycard.html). This suggests that Cohn is not likely the person who came up with it, given that his first mentions of it appear to be a couple years later.

Comment: This evidence is also present in Chapter 7 of User Story Mapping: Discover the Whole Story, Build the Right Product.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it attributed to Mike Cohn, for example at [CollabNet blog](http://scrummethodology.com/scrum-user-stories/).  Don't know if he actually got it from elsewhere, but you could probably ask him.

Comment: Thanks, I did find a couple of things from your post (which leads me to believe Cohn is the author):
http://agileconsortium.pbworks.com/f/Intro_to_User_stories.pdf
and
http://blog.mountaingoatsoftware.com/advantages-of-the-as-a-user-i-want-user-story-template